# How come this android code is working on emulator but does not work on the device?

Tags: android, events

I am developing a little app(with minimum sdk requirement of Android OS ver 2.3.3) that has the following functionality:

When the user presses the **volume decrease button**  *exactly 3 times*, then a toast message appears. Here is the code:

```
static short btnCount=0;

@Override
        public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            btnCount++;
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN) && btnCount==3){
                //Do something
                Toast.makeText(this, "Volume Button Pressed", 2).show();
                btnCount=0;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.testvolumeapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.testvolumeapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It works perfectly fine on the emulator but for some reason it is not working on my HTC having Android OS version 2.3.5. Why is that? What could have gone wrong?

Comment: any error ? what logcat says ?

Comment: Remember that the static variable will be reset (back to zero) when orientation of device changes.  This is easier to do with a real device, than emulator.  Probably a better idea to keep the `btnCount` variable in a bundle variable as discussed here `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29`

Comment: @Diederik That's another approach to do the same thing. I did reset the static the variable back to zero. The question is why this piece of code is not working on the device as it is working perfectly fine on the emulator.

Comment: Perhaps, this button has another key code on your HTC. Simply press the key and see, which code it has (use breakpoint or logcat)

Comment: Your question refers to "Increase volume button" but the code expects `KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN` Could that be the mistake?

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. Let me edit it. But even then, it doesn't work.

Comment: @a.ch Yupp! You are absolutely right! The keycode on HTC is different. On the emulator it was different. So what am I suppose to do for making a general app. There would be key codes different for different Android phones like: Samsung, Nexus, Motorola, etc. Any idea how can we address this problem?

Comment: I cannot invent anything better than introducing `IKeyCodes` interface and its different implementations (i.e. `HTCKeyCodes`, `SamsungKeyCodes`, etc), which would be dynamically loaded according to device your app is running on. I suppose that vendors in general follow the standards, so you wouldn't need many implementations

Comment: @a.ch. I see. Is this what you are talking about: https://www.assembla.com/code/genexus_standard_classes-fork/subversion/nodes/trunk/Java/sources/com/genexus/uifactory/IKeyCodes.java?rev=12. I would really be interested to know how do you use it?

Comment: No, I didn't mean that ))
I only meant [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) and [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html)